# Dynamic Content - Exchange Content upon User Interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am just starting out with JavaScript. This is what I am trying to do:

I want to make a website, lets say about football. When a user lands on the website, he or she will see a default text about football. The user now has the chance to use 4 buttons:

Button 1: **Fan** |
Button 2: **Not a football fan** |
Button 3: **Long** |
Button 4: **Short** |

Button 1 and 2 will change the content accordingly. So there is a text written for non-fans and one for fans (and a default one).

Button 3 and 4 will change the lenght of the content to either a short or long copy of the current text. So if the user selected "fan" and "short" the default content would change to the short version of the fan-written-text.

I hope I explained it clearly. Now from my research I figured I could use something like this:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "I am individualized   content."
```

But is this really the way to go? Furthermore my research suggests that react.js may be the best thing to use here.

I am not looking for a ready-made-solution here. I would love for someone to guide me in the right direction with some background knowledge if possible.

Any suggestions? :) Thanks.

Comment: You can definitly achieve this with react, whether it is the best solution or not is another question ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want just a guide to the right direction, you have several options:

1. Use pure javascript
2. Use jQuery
3. Use React.js
4. Other (for example Angular.js)

To do your task with a pure javascript you have found the right function to change content. Now all you need to do is have two variables (for holding short/long information and another one for holding fan/not-fan).

By having these two variables you can easily find what buttons were clicked and what content to load by checking them with if sentences.